# Counter of nested enumerate environment isn't displayed

Tags: enumerate, babel

I am using two nested `enumerate` environments and the 6th's counter isn't displayed although I get no errors or warnings. Why is that? How do I fix it?

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont
[
    UprightFont = *,
    BoldFont = *Bold,
    ItalicFont = *It,
    BoldItalicFont = *BoldIt,
    Extension = .otf,
    Ligatures = TeX,
    Mapping = tex-text
]{GFSArtemisia}

\setsansfont
[
    Mapping = tex-text
]{GFSArtemisia.otf}


\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

Text

\begin{enumerate}

\item Item 1

\begin{enumerate}

\item Item 1

\item Item 2

\item Item 3

\item Item 4

\item Item 5

\item Item 6

\item Item 7

\item Item 8

\item Item 9

\item Item 10

\end{enumerate}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: the 6th "greek alpha" numeral is `\stigma`, which isn't present in (at least) the computer modern fonts.  it *should be* present in `unicode-math`, but it has the name `\upstigma` (`\upStigma` for uppercase).  so if you add `\let\stigma\upstigma` after loading `unicode-math`, i think that should give the result you want.  by the way, this really is a function of `babel`, so that would be a useful addition to the tags.

Comment: @barbarabeeton It didn't work. Regarding the tag I will edit my question.

Comment: @egreg It doesn't work with GFSNeohellenic either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right in loading `babel` after `fontspec`. However, the GSF Artemisia font has no glyph at U+03DB GREEK SMALL LETTER STIGMA, but only the uppercase variant at U+03DA GREEK LETTER STIGMA.

Happily, the aspect of the glyph at U+03DA is lowercase, so you can use it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\setmainfont[
    UprightFont = *,
    BoldFont = *Bold,
    ItalicFont = *It,
    BoldItalicFont = *BoldIt,
    Extension = .otf,
]{GFSArtemisia}

\setsansfont[
]{GFSArtemisia.otf}

\let\textstigma\textStigma

\begin{document}

Text

\begin{enumerate}

\item Item 1

\begin{enumerate}

\item Item 1

\item Item 2

\item Item 3

\item Item 4

\item Item 5

\item Item 6

\item Item 7

\item Item 8

\item Item 9

\item Item 10

\end{enumerate}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternative solution: use GFS Didot for the two variants of stigma.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\setmainfont[
    UprightFont = *,
    BoldFont = *Bold,
    ItalicFont = *It,
    BoldItalicFont = *BoldIt,
    Extension = .otf,
]{GFSArtemisia}

\setsansfont[
  Extension = .otf,
]{GFSArtemisia}

\newfontfamily{\didot}[
  Extension = .otf,
]{GFSDidot}

\DeclareTextCommand{\textStigma}{\LastDeclaredEncoding}{{\didot Ϛ}}
\DeclareTextCommand{\textstigma}{\LastDeclaredEncoding}{{\didot ϛ}}

\begin{document}

Text

\begin{enumerate}

\item Item 1

\begin{enumerate}

\item Item 1

\item Item 2

\item Item 3

\item Item 4

\item Item 5

\item Item 6

\item Item 7

\item Item 8

\item Item 9

\item Item 10

\end{enumerate}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want “στ” instead of the old letter, you can do as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\setmainfont[
    UprightFont = *,
    BoldFont = *Bold,
    ItalicFont = *It,
    BoldItalicFont = *BoldIt,
    Extension = .otf,
]{GFSArtemisia}

\setsansfont[
  Extension = .otf,
]{GFSArtemisia}

\DeclareTextCommand{\textStigma}{\LastDeclaredEncoding}{ΣΤ}
\DeclareTextCommand{\textstigma}{\LastDeclaredEncoding}{στ}

\begin{document}

Text

\begin{enumerate}

\item Item 1

\begin{enumerate}

\item Item 1

\item Item 2

\item Item 3

\item Item 4

\item Item 5

\item Item 6

\item Item 7

\item Item 8

\item Item 9

\item Item 10

\end{enumerate}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document
```

[image]

Comment: Normally it should be "στ" and not "ς". Is there a solution for that? :P

Comment: @Adam Added the solution with the character combination

Comment: Your last solution worked although only after moving `unicode-math` which is weird. In its documentation it says that it must be loaded after font declarations but only works if I load it before `fontspec` and `babel`. If I place it after those package it doesn't work. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

`unicode-math` should be loaded always loaded after other font-settings, this will cure the missing item number problem.

In addition, I recommend to use `polyglossia` instead of babel:

```
\documentclass{article}


%\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage[variant=modern]{greek}
\setotherlanguage{english}


\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont
[
    UprightFont = *,
    BoldFont = *Bold,
    ItalicFont = *It,
    BoldItalicFont = *BoldIt,
    Extension = .otf,
    Ligatures = TeX,
    Mapping = tex-text
]{GFSArtemisia}

\setsansfont
[
   Mapping = tex-text
]{GFSArtemisia.otf}




\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

Text

\begin{enumerate}

\item Item 1

\begin{enumerate}

\item Item 1

\item Item 2

\item Item 3

\item Item 4

\item Item 5

\item Item 6

\item Item 7

\item Item 8

\item Item 9

\item Item 10

\end{enumerate}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was told explicitly in a question of mine a while back that `unicode-math` should be loaded before the font declarations. I even have that written in comments in my preamble :P

Comment: @Adam: Look at your preamble: It's before `\setmainfont` etc.

Comment: Yes that is what I told you. :P

Comment: @Adam: The `unicode-math` manual clearly states that it should be loaded **after** font-settings.

Comment: I load `unicode-math` after the font declarations and it completely destroys the document!

Comment: @Adam: Define `completely` destroys the document? Did you have used `polyglossia` as well?

Comment: I only see random symbols and numbers. No without polyglossia.

Comment: @Adam: Why do you think I've added `polyglossia`? ;-)

Comment: Oh I see. Then I will try it that way!